# ngx-material-virtual keyboard is not supporting keyup events

Tags: angular

I'm using Virtual Keyboard for my one of Angular Project where i want to use keyUp event for input validation but not able to use keyup/keydown/keypress any events for virtual keyboard .Events are working fine for hardware Keyboard so there is no syntax error.

## my code is as below

```html
<input class="search type="text" matInput [matKeyboard]="'Azərbaycanca'"
placeholder="Search for a song" (keyup.enter)="search_result();(enterClick)="closeCurrentKeyboard();" (keyup)="function();">
```

## Virtual keyboard i am using is refrenced from this link-->

https://github.com/ngx-material-keyboard/core

I had tried a lot of substitute but not able to get perfect solution.Please help me with Solution.

Comment: A bit late, but in line 166 of https://github.com/ngx-material-keyboard/core/blob/master/src/core/src/components/keyboard/keyboard.component.ts I can see an onKeyUp event. You don't need to add a handler to your HTML, a HostListener already serves keyup handling (also keydown, of course).